# How to upgrade eclipse on macOS 12.6.7 monteray from 2020-06 to higher versions?

Tags: eclipse, macos, upgrade

I always get this error when I attempt to perform Help -> Check for updates and there is no clear error details to get out of this upgrade blocker hell. Any help is much appreciated!

**EDIT** Adding the `~/workspace/.metadata/.log` file. [eclipse.log](https://gist.github.com/msmygit/9e48348c434578f254578bc627f32b29)

> *p/s I understand I've an option to perform a fresh install, but wanted to see how to fix this upgrade problem*

[image]
[image]

Comment: For that old version I would recommend to do a fresh installation. Otherwise, please tell why a fresh installation does not work for you and add more information to your question: go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error (do not open it, just select it), hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_.

Comment: Bundle signing changed dramatically in between then and now. A fresh reinstall would be best.

Comment: This is exactly the same problem even when I'm trying to update from 2022-03. (I'll collect the error log shortly here)

Comment: I've updated the original question with the error log gist

Comment: another error log from [2022-03 upgrade effort](https://gist.github.com/msmygit/2b055ca95f38bb3e529cba98e11caa35)

Comment: I'm unsure/puzzled why eclipse didn't auto-download-update when I've that setting turned ON by defaul ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as answer as comment wouldn't allow so many characters.

Here is another example of an error from 2022-03

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.axis,1.4.0.v20230730-0709
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.commons.discovery,0.5.0
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.wsil4j,1.0.0.v20230815-1152
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore,2.35.0.v20230801-1141
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.ui,2.35.0.v20230622-1149
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.core,1.5.0.v202307260438
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.server.core,1.2.800.v202308172116
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.core,1.0.1000.v202308172116
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxrs.core,1.1.0.v202308010229
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxrs.ui,1.1.0.v202308010145
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.command.env.ui,1.2.0.v202308012257
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.css.ui,1.2.200.v202308160453
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.core,1.11.0.v202308172116
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.discovery,1.3.500.v202308172116
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.ui,1.6.200.v202308172116
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xsd,2.19.0.v20230614-0642
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.uddi4j,2.0.5.v20230815-1152
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.axis.ant,1.4.0.v20230825-1400
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore,2.35.0.v20230801-1141
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.ui,2.35.0.v20230622-1149
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf,2.35.0.v20230829-0934
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_core.feature,3.31.0.v202308010354
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_ui.feature,3.31.0.v202308110616
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jst.server_core.feature,3.4.600.v202308172116
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.nebula.cwt,1.1.0.202303072132
```